# ¿Cómo silenciar un iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

necesito ayuda para silenciar un iframe (vid1) cuando haga clic en un botón cerrar.
mi caso es que tengo un div que contiene un iframe, este div tiene un botón cerrar (display:none), pero cuando se oculta el div, el iframe sigue sonando. gracias.

```
<div id="cont1">
         <div class="cerrar" onclick="ocultar();"></div>
          <div class="video_mod">
  <iframe id="vid1" class="video_cont" src="https://virtual.usergioarboleda.edu.co/mod/hvp/embed.php?id=431756" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><script src="https://virtual.usergioarboleda.edu.co/mod/hvp/library/js/h5p-resizer.js" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
           </div>           
      </div>
```

Comment: adicional este iframe no esta en mi dominio, es decir no puedo controlar los objetos que estan dentro, queria saber si se puede silenciar o pausar, de alguna forma

Comment: puedes usar javascript para que tenga una accion o funcion mute al video.

Answer (score 0):

englobalo en un div y con innetHtml quitale el contenido

```
<div id="parentiframediv">

</div>
```

a la función de ocultar le pones

```
document.getElementById("parentiframediv").innerHTML = " ";
```